# Export topology checker results as table/shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, topology

I have used the plugin "topology checker" and I got table with all the topology errors :
[image]

I would like to save this table as new layer/ csv or any way  I can export it.

I saw there were disccussion about it few years ago in github but couldn't find any feature to do that.

Is there any way to export this table?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to export the results of topology checker as CSV or shapefile.  I doubt you can even copy and paste the data into text editor, but try to do that for confirmation.

Comment: @ahmadhanb I couldn't copy it

Comment: Then, I don’t think there is a way to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a bit of a hack I came up with which should do what you want. With the Topology Checker dock widget open and the table populated with some errors, open the Python console, paste the following code into an editor and run. **Note*** the only thing you need to do is edit the *third line* of the script to specify the file path to the location where you want the output CSV to be created and what you want it to be named.

Enjoy!

```py
import csv

# Edit line below for your desired output location (the csv will be created)
out_path = 'C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\Topology_errors.csv' # example

check_dock = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'checkDock')
main_widget = check_dock.findChild(QWidget, 'dockWidgetContents')
tbl = main_widget.findChild(QTableView, 'mErrorTableView')
out_file = open(out_path, 'w', newline='')

def export_errors(table, output):
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    mod = table.model()
    num_rows = mod.rowCount()
    num_cols = mod.columnCount()
    headers = []
    for n in range(num_cols):
        headers.append(mod.headerData(n, Qt.Horizontal))
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for i in range(num_rows):
        errors = []
        for j in range(num_cols):
            index = mod.index(i, j)
            errors.append(mod.data(index))
        writer.writerow(errors)


export_errors(tbl, out_file)
out_file.close()
```

Comment: thank you very much! do you know any way to add also desired field from the original layer to the topology csv?

Comment: Hi Ben do you know how to access to instance from rulesDialog.ui ? because I can't acces to attribute check_dock.mConfigureDialog